# Name of the parts in a function member declaration

Tags: c++, function, c++11, standards, vocabulary

In C++, the type of a function member can be seen as :

```
R(C::*)(Args...) qualifiers/specifiers
```

I am wondering if the part that is before the `(Args...)` has an official name (I mean `R(C::*)`)? (like the function declarator or something like that)

Comment: look at this site maybe http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R(C::*)` doesn't have a name. It's the concatenation of two different kinds of grammar productions. `R` is a *type-specifier-seq* whereas `(C::*)` is a *noptr-abstract-declarator*. But a *noptr-abstract-declarator* binds to *parameters-and-qualifiers*, *i.e.,* `(Args...)` and so on, more strongly than to the *type-specifier-seq*. It's a bit like how in the expression `1+2*3` there is no name for the substring `1+2` since it has no independent meaning.